# Change color of plotband dynamically

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to change color of plotband dynamically in highcharts?
I have more than one plotband and want to change color of other plotbands when there is click action on one of plotband.

Comment: check here https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/3563013-add-ability-to-dynamically-change-plotband-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom-events extension, which allows to catch click event on plotband. Next step is update color by attr() function, direcly on SVG element.

```
plotBands: [{ 
                    color: '#FCFFC5',
                    from: 100,
                    to: 200,
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            this.svgElem.attr({
                                fill:'red'
                            });
                        }
                    }
    }]
```

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/Utx8g/412/